# JSplitPane + MiGLayout: how to enable proportional autoresizing

Tags: java, swing, miglayout, jsplitpane

A followup question [to my other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833383/jsplitpane-miglayout-how-to-enable-autoresizing/4834251#4834251);

How do I enable proportional resizing? I thought this would work but it doesn't:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class SplitPaneQuestion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SplitPaneQuestion");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        panel.setLayout(new MigLayout("","[]","[grow]"));
        JSplitPane splitpane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
        panel.add(splitpane, "push, grow");

        splitpane.setTopComponent(new JButton("top"));
        splitpane.setBottomComponent(new JButton("bottom"));
        splitpane.setDividerLocation(0.333);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

What I would like is for the ratio of the top/bottom button sizes to be constant when I resize the entire frame. (with a 1:2 ratio by default)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
splitPane.setResizeWeight(0.333);
```

Comment: Aha! thanks, I was expecting setDividerLocation to work and when it didn't I had no idea what to do instead.

Answer (score 2):

I can't talk for MigLayout, which I do not know. However, to my mind, the best solution to that issue is swing-generic : you add a [`ComponentListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html) to your JSpiltPane and resize its contained component by a coefficient built from size ratio.

Comment: +1: I need to do this for other purposes, so thanks for the link to ComponentListener.